# Can I set up a global GTK accelerator for mouse buttons?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm modifying an existing GTK3 application, and want to handle the "back" and "forward" mouse buttons (with integer values of 8 and 9, respectively) globally.

I tried attaching a signal handler to the window:

```
g_signal_connect(window, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(onButtonPress), NULL);
```

This works assuming the widget underneath the cursor also doesn't handle button presses (e.g. a click / button handler for a normal button), in which case the event does not propagate up to the window as it is handled by the widget.

Key events are sent to accelerators first before the underlying widget, which is the behavior I want, but I'm using mouse buttons which don't seem to be supported as accelerators or mnemonics.

How can I setup a window-level handler for mouse buttons in this way?

Here's a reference for GTK event handling and propagation: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-input-handling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a global GDK event handler that will deliver these button events to the top-level window:

```
#define BUTTON_FORWARD   8
#define BUTTON_BACK      9

static void redirect_button_events(GdkEvent *event) {
    if (event->type != GDK_BUTTON_PRESS)
        return;

    GtkWidget *widget = gtk_get_event_widget(event);

    if (widget == NULL)
        return;

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_widget_get_toplevel(widget);

    if (window == NULL)
        return;

    switch (event->button.button) {

    case BUTTON_FORWARD:
    case BUTTON_BACK:
        event->any.window = gtk_widget_get_window(window);
        /* XXX: fix up mouse coordinates if needed */
        break;

    }
}

static void event_handler(GdkEvent *event, void *_) {
    redirect_button_events(event);
    gtk_main_do_event(event);
}
```

You can install this handler with [`gdk_event_handler_set`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Events.html#gdk-event-handler-set), right after invoking `gtk_main`:

```
gdk_event_handler_set(&event_handler, NULL, NULL);
```

With this handler, events involving buttons 8 and 9 will be delivered to the top-level window. You can then attach `button-press-event` signal handlers to the window, as you intended originally.

You can even dispense with the window signal handler entirely and handle button events in the global handler directly.